# Why Mongoose doesn't validate on update?

Tags: mongoose

I have this code

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true}
});

var Client = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

Using express, I create a new client with this code

```
var client = new Client(req.body);
client.save(function(err, data) {
  ....
});
```

If I leave the name field empty on the form, mongoose doesn't allow to create the client because I set it as required on the schema. Also, if I leave spaces before and after the name, mongoose delete that spaces before save.

Now, I try to update a client with this code

```
var id = req.params.id;
var client = req.body;
Client.update({_id: id}, client, function(err) {
  ....
});
```

It let me to change the name, but if I leave it empty on the form, mongoose doesn't validate and save an empty name. If I add empty spaces before and after the name, it save the name with spaces.

Why mongoose validate on save but not on update? I'm doing it in the wrong way?

mongodb: 2.4.0
mongoose: 3.6.0
express: 3.1.0
node: 0.10.1

Comment: which approach you went ahead with? Just curious, facing exact same issue. Can you please share example in here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, [`validation`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) is implemented as internal middleware within Mongoose and middleware doesn't get executed during an `update` as that's basically a pass-through to the native driver.

If you want your client update validated you'll need to `find` the object to update, apply the new property values to it (see underscore's [`extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) method), and then call `save` on it.

**Mongoose 4.0 Update**

As noted in the comments and victorkohl's answer, Mongoose now support the validation of the fields of `$set` and `$unset` operators when you include the `runValidators: true` option in the `update` call.

Comment: There is some GitHub tickets about Mongoose validation on update, see [Issue 860](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/860), [Issue 892](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/892) and also [Issue 4722](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/4722). I hope they will fix this soon..

Comment: _.extend really helped me out here as I needed to update a number of different subdocument fields from a partial json object. Thankyou!

Comment: From v3.9.3, update() takes 2 additional options: setDefaultsOnInsert and runValidators
@see https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commit/1d8c3e96c7b11497d3325e9cf1f7ae66c9ee560e

Comment: I usually get the document, then use Lo-Dash's merge method to do a deep extend in case I have nested properties....https://lodash.com/docs#merge

Answer (score 113):

As of Mongoose 4.0 you [can run validators](http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm) on `update()` and `findOneAndUpdate()` using the new flag `runValidators: true`.

> Mongoose 4.0 introduces an option to run validators on `update()` and
> `findOneAndUpdate()` calls. Turning this option on will run validators
> for all fields that your `update()` call tries to `$set` or `$unset`.

For example, given OP's Schema:

```js
const ClientSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true}
});

const Client = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

**Passing the flag on each update**

You can use the new flag like this:

```js
const id = req.params.id;
const client = req.body;
Client.update({_id: id}, client, { runValidators: true }, function(err) {
  ....
});
```

**Using the flag on a `pre` hook**

If you don't want to set the flag every time you update something, you can set a `pre` hook for `findOneAndUpdate()`:

```js
// Pre hook for `findOneAndUpdate`
ClientSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
  this.options.runValidators = true;
  next();
});
```

Then you can `update()` using the validators without passing the `runValidators`  flag every time.

Comment: I liked this answer, but the prehook for findOneAndUpdate throws a mongoose error...  looks like it might be due to that method not being supported?  Also, just specifying the "update" prehook does not fire the validations..  The error: /.../mongoose/node_modules/hooks/hooks.js:149
    if ('undefined' === typeof proto[methodName].numAsyncPres) {

Comment: Doug, the query middleware for adding hooks to findONeAndUpdate was added in Mongoose 4.0 (https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2138). Are you sure you are using Mongoose 4.0 or above?

Comment: Specifying `{ runValidators: true }` on the update calls works great.  But **pre hook option set does not work** for me in Mongoose version 4.1.0

Answer (score 16):

MongoDB does not run validation on updates by default.

in order to make validation works by default when an update happens, just before connecting to MongoDB you can set global setting only ones like that:

```
mongoose.set('runValidators', true); // here is your global setting

mongoose.connect(config.database, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connection has been made, start making fireworks...');
}).on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('Connection error:', error);
});
```

So any built-in or custom validation will run on any update as well

Comment: Do you **have** to set this before connecting to the database or is it sufficient to set it afterwards? It seems to work either way.

Answer (score 3):

You can run validation while update by setting the option `runValidators: true`.

#### Example 1:

```
const Kitten = db.model('Kitten', kittenSchema);

const update = { color: 'blue' };
const opts = { runValidators: true };
Kitten.updateOne({}, update, opts, function() {
  // code
});
```

#### Example 2:

```
const Kitten = db.model('Kitten', kittenSchema);

const update = { color: 'blue' };
const opts = { runValidators: true };
Kitten.updateOne(
  {
    _id: req.params.id
  },
  {
    $set: { ...update },
  },
  opts
).then(result => {
    // code
})
```

Read More: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not work if you use `upsert` in the `findOneAndUpdate` options. The way around this is to create a model static method that does a `findOne` and then `updateOne` or `create` under the hood. `create` runs validation automatically.

```
export async function findOneAndUpdateWithValidation(
  this: LocationModel,
  filter: FilterQuery<LocationDocument>,
  update: UpdateQuery<LocationDocument>,
  options?: QueryOptions
) {
  const documentFound = await this.findOne(filter);
  
  if (!documentFound) return this.create(update);

  return this.updateOne(filter, update, options);
}

locationSchema.statics = {
  findOneAndUpdateWithValidation
}
```

Comment: Jamie I am upvoting this answer as it actually solves the issue. I spent the last day obsessing on this issue and here is a Generic solution to the problem with inspiration from your work. https://gist.github.com/Corky3892/2452203657e5a31423d990faddf4ebad

Answer (score 0):

If you add this option in your config of mongoose it works:

```
mongoose.set('runValidators', true)
```

Comment: This is just the same as - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53856167/1682790 - (above), which was submitted two years before you.

Answer (score -1):

In your model, ex. Category.js file:

```
const CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
category_name : {
type : String,
required : [true, 'Category Name Is Required !'],
trim : true,
maxlength : [30, 'Category Name Is To Long !'],
unique : true,
});
const Category = module.exports = mongoose.model("Category",CategorySchema);
```

In your route file:

```
router.put("/",(req,res,next)=>{
  Category.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id : req.body.categoryId},
  {$set : {category_name : req.body.category_name} },
  **{runValidators: true}**, function(err,result) {
    if(err){
      if(err.code === 11000){
       var duplicateValue = err.message.match(/".*"/);
       res.status(200).json({"defaultError":duplicateValue[0]+" Is Already Exsist !"});
       }else{
         res.status(200).json({"error":err.message} || {"defaultError":'Error But Not Understood !'});
       }
    }else{
     console.log("From category.js (Route File) = "+result);
     res.status(200).json({"success":"Category Updated Successfully!!"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please explain what the code aims to do. Also, syntax highlighting helps.