# Does Moongoose 3.8.8 support $position operator?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Does Moongoose 3.8.8 (the lastest version) support $position (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) operator from MongoDB 2.6.0?

In the following code example the new elements is inserted in the end of the array userActivity.activities:

model:

```
var userActivity = new schema({
    userId: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    activities: [activity]
});

var activity = new schema({
    act: {type: Number, required:true},
});
```

query:

```
var activity = { act: 1 };

model.userActivity.update(
{ _id: dbact._id },
{ $push: { activities: {
                $each: [ activity ],
                $position: 0
            }
         }
},
function (err, numAffected) {
    if (!err) {
    // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually doesn't matter and never matters for any "framework" implementation and I do not mind explaining why.

Every single "framework" ( such as Mongoose, Mongoid, Doctrine, MongoEngine, etc, etc, etc ) are all basically built upon a basic "driver" implementation that has in most cases been developedby the MongoDB staff themselves. So the basic functionality is always ther even if you need to "delve" down to a level in order to use those "native" methods.

---

So here would be the native usage example in this case:

```js
List.collection.update(
{},
{ "$push": {
    "list": {
      "$each": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
      "$position": 0 }
    }
},function(err,NumAffected) {
  console.log("done");

});
```

Note the "collection" method used from the model, which is getting the "raw" collection details from the driver. So you are using it's method and not some "wrapped" method that may be doing additional processing.

---

The next and most basic reason is if you cannot find the method and application of the operators that you need the here is a simple fact.

Every single operation as used by the methods in every framework and basic driver method is essentially a call to the "runCommand" method in the basic API. So since that basic call is available everywhere ( in some form or another, because it has to be ), then you can do everything that you find advertised on the MongoDB site with every language implementation on **any** framework.

But the short call to your particular request is, since this is not actually a **method** call but is simply part of the BSON arguments as passed in, then of course there is no restriction by a particular language driver to actually use this.

So you can use these new argument without of course updating to the most recent version. But you probably will get some nice methods to do so if you actually do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Unfortunately, it seems that $push together with $position doesn't work (I use the latest MongoDb 2.6 and the latest Mongoose 3.8.8) - the $position operator is ignored and new element is inserted in the end of array!

Comment: @Roman as explained in the answer this has nothing to do with Mongoose. If you are not getting an expected result using 2.6 then your syntax is wrong. Array indexes start from 0 as the first element. So if that still is a problem then you would be better to show your statement than just ask "does it work"

Comment: @Roman so what I was generally explaining and have now included a sample for it, is you can always get down to the "raw" driver level in every framework. So while it seems the mongoose methods are messing with the update document that is provided, the raw driver usage will work as expected. See the code in the edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work yet for me.. MongoDB 2.6.0 and Mongoose 3.8.8. I don't know what am I doing wrong.. I have tried "$push"-"$each"-"$position" (as in your example) and $push-$each-$position (as in the message below)

Comment: @Roman It certainly does work. Look at the example, you need to call the **collection** method on the model as is shown. I have run this under exactly the same environment.

Comment: Yep! but it seems this works only for nested arrays in the document.. For "subdocument.list" this doesn't work: List.collection.update({}, { "$push": {
    "subdocument.list": {
      "$each": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
      "$position": 0 }
    }
Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: @Roman It is very likely you are doing something wrong, but yet again you are asking questions that are not actually a part of your question. So your question was "can you use this operator" and you have been shown, yes you can and how you can do it. If you have another question then feel free to post another question here. And if you show what you are doing then you will get an answer. But your general question has been answered.

Comment: I have created one more topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083041/how-to-insert-to-the-certain-position-in-the-array-in-the-subdocument-by-using-m

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use it directly as Mongoose will [pass through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15629463/95190) the update clause:

```
Model.update(
  query, /* match the document */ 
  { $push: 
       { yourArrayField: 
                 {
                    $each: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
                    $position: 0
                 }
       }
  }, function (err, res) { /* callback */ });
```

The above would insert the values `1, 2, 3` at the front of the array named `yourArrayField`.

As it's just a pass-through, you'll need to make sure it works with the server version that you're connecting the client to.