# findAndModify MongoDB insert element at beginning of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Update:
Problem here was that the native MongoDB driver needed the objectID in a different format than Mongoose.  Instead of {_id: story_id} I needed to do, {_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(story_id)}. The reason it returned just the two fields was that it was creating a new document with {_id: story_id} rather than updating the document which was {_id: {$oid: story_id}}.  However, my original reason for doing this with the native driver vs. mongoose turned out to not work.  Even the native driver does not accept positive $slice values. So I'm still looking for a way to insert an object to the beginning of an array using Mongoose or the native driver accessed through Mongoose (which does not support $position or positive $slice values).

When I run the query below, the returned results only include _id, messages and participants.  I would like to get the full story record back rather than just the updated fields. Is there a way to do this?  Based on Node MongoDB Native driver documentation (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) the "fields" parameter from the mongo console is not implemented in the findAndModify driver.  I want to avoid having to do a second query to get the just updated record.

```
Story.collection.findAndModify(
{"_id": story_id},
{"_id": "asc"},
{ 
    "$push": {
"messages": {
  "$each": [message],
  "$sort": { "_id": -1},
  "$slice": 500 
    },
  },
    "$addToSet": {"participants": user_id},
},
    {new: true},
    {fields: {"feeling":1, "description":1, "image_height":1, "image_width":1, "storyteller":1, "image_url":1, "participants":1}},   // -> this line is ignored by MongoDB native driver

      {upsert: true}

)
```

Comment: If you're using Mongoose, why aren't you calling [`Story.findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)?  Regardless, you should get the whole doc back, not just the updated fields.

Comment: Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate doesn't have support for adding to the beginning of array, as I am doing here with $sort and $slice (Mongoose looks for negative $slice values and returns an error.  This query as shown here does not return the whole doc back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert elements at the beginning of an array field with a `$push` that uses the `$each` and [`$position`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position) modifiers (which is supported by Mongoose):

```
Story.findByIdAndUpdate(story_id, {
    $push: {
      messages: {
        $each: [message],
        $position: 0
      },
    },
    $addToSet: {participants: user_id},
  }, {
    new: true,
    upsert: true
  },
  function (err, newDoc) { ... }
);
```

Comment: Mongoose does not support passing through of the $position parameter.  See: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2024  and last reply here" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083041/how-to-insert-to-the-certain-position-in-the-array-in-the-subdocument-by-using-m   The error from mongoose is that $each can only be paired with $sort or $slice

Comment: @PraneethWanigasekera That bug is marked as [fixed in 3.8.12](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commit/6cddf8441dad0d6fb9c4588d4cb05b7d71d44b90) and it worked fine when I tested it with Mongoose 3.8.16.

Comment: it would be awesome if it worked.  I am using 3.8.16 too.  Here's the error I get with the above code: { [OperationalError: exception: $each term takes only $slice (and optionally $sort) as complements]
  name: 'OperationalError',
  message: 'exception: $each term takes only $slice (and optionally $sort) as complements',
  cause: 
   { [MongoError: exception: $each term takes only $slice (and optionally $sort) as complements]   Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @PraneethWanigasekera `$position` support was added in MongoDB 2.6. What server version are you running?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think that's what's going on. My Mongolab db version which I don't have control over is 2.4.5 I believe.

Comment: I was able to get my db version changed and this worked perfectly. Thanks!