# mongodb, express.js. Add new doc to array of documents selector is id

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I want to add a new document to an array of documents. So I pass in my param which is the _id of the document I want to add to. Then I need to just add it to the array. I thought I had it working but it was actually adding a nested array to that array. I realized this because I am also trying to sort it so newly added documents are at top. So I ended up having to go back and try and fix my add query. As of now it basically just says cannot add values. This is why I have been using mongodb client, express, await.

I have been looking at mongodb manual and trying what they have but cannot get it to work, obviously something wrong with my adding of new document. Anyone see the issue or show me an example? Thanks!

```
app.post("/addComment/:id", async (request, response) => {
    let mongoClient = new MongoClient(URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    try {
        await mongoClient.connect(); 
        let id = new ObjectId(request.sanitize(request.params.id));

       
        request.body.comments = { $push: {"comments.author": "myTestPOSTMAN - 1", "comments.comment": 
        "myTestCommPostMan - 1"}};

        let selector = { "_id":id };
        //let newValues = {$push: {"comments.comment": "myTestCommPostMan - 1", "comments.author": 
        "myTestPOSTMAN - 1"}};
        let newValues = request.body.comments;
        let result = await mongoClient.db(DB_NAME).collection("photos").updateOne(selector, 
        newValues);

        if (JSON.parse(result).n <= 0) {
            response.status(404);
            response.send({error: "No documents found with ID"});
            mongoClient.close();
            return;
        }
        response.status(200);
        response.send(result);     
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500);
        response.send({error: error.message});
        throw error;
    } finally {
        mongoClient.close();
    }
});
```

Using post man this is what my json looks like and what the array of documents looks like I am trying to add to.

```
 {"comments": [
                {
                    "comment": "pm - test3",
                    "author": "pm - test4"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Ever considered of pulling down that document you want edit and have it in memory then perform all manipulations you want the just update the entire document once done

Comment: no I just thought write a query and add the new values, figured it was a simple enough task, but I am also new to mongodb. I have mostly used sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- do the mongodb connection outside the function, no need to connect and disconnect everytime when function call, don't create unusual variables too much.
- for push object you need to provide main key name and assign object to it.

```
let mongoClient = new MongoClient(URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
await mongoClient.connect();
app.post("/addComment/:id", async (request, response) => {

    try {

        let result = await mongoClient.db(DB_NAME).collection("photos").updateOne(
            { "_id": new ObjectId(request.sanitize(request.params.id)) }, 
            { $push: { comments: request.body.comments } }
        );
        if (JSON.parse(result).n <= 0) {
            response.status(404).send({ error: "No documents found with ID" });
            return;
        }
        response.status(200).send(result);

    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
    }

});
```

Comment: ahh I get it. Well I was able to learn from what you provided and add an object to it with success. Why are you indexing 0 though?

Comment: I thought you are passing an array, i have just corrected.

Comment: basically adding somthing like this let string = {author: "myname", comment: "mycomment"}; but indexing it like you did would I be able place the newly added document to a desired index? Nm tried it and doesnt do anything

Comment: what index are you talking about `comments` array element index? no $push will add object in at the end of array. means last element.

Comment: yeah I thought by changing the index it would push it to that index but it didnt do anything

Comment: no you can use $position and $each operator inside $push to push object in specific position check [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) and example [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083041/how-to-insert-to-the-certain-position-in-the-array-in-the-subdocument-by-using-m)