# How to findOneAndUpdate adding value in front of the Array in the subdocument by using Mongoose - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A great explanation of how to UPDATE and  use `$push` and `$position` operators of Mongodb 2.6 by using Mongoose was given in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063387/does-moongoose-3-8-8-support-position-operator?answertab=active#tab-top) to my question. The suggested solution works perfect with the `$push` operator. If I use `$addToSet` operator it doesn't work. Here is the code that I tried:

```
const curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()

      curValueSchema.symbol = curValue
      highLow.map(item => {
        curValueSchema.data.push(item)
      })

      const query = { symbol: `${curValue}` }
      const update = { $addToSet: { data: curValueSchema.data, $position: 0 } }
      const options = { upsert: true, new: true }

      parentSchemaSymbol.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(doc => {
        console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
        return res.send(highLow)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
```

**Error message**

```
{ MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$position' in '$position' is not valid for storage.
ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$position\' in \'$position\' is not valid for storage.',
  code: 52,
  codeName: 'DollarPrefixedFieldName',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: looking through the docs. $position seems to be available on $push operator and not to $addToSet operator.

Comment: @AadhiVive you are right! Is there way to use $addToSet and add the value in front of the Array or I have to drop it and use $push?

Comment: sorry unfortunately no. Try with $push. Seems to get closer to the result you are looking for. Other option is to find the document and then manually array.unshift() then use findOneAndUpdate the whole array.

Comment: @AadhiVive looks like $push is giving more control to handle the data.