# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate seems to bypass my pre "save" hook and returns stale data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, put

I have a pre "save" hook on my User model for password encryption using bcrypt that works just fine when creating a new user record. However, when editing the user (I'm using findByIdAndUpdate for brevity) and changing the password, it seems to bypass that hook and save as plain text. From the Mongoose documentation, I was led to believe that any update events call the "save" middleware, so why would this be happening and how do I fix it?

Additionally, despite using async/await, the response is returning n-1 data.

```
exports.editUser = async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const user = await db.User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {useFindAndModify: false}); 
    return res.status('200').json(user); 
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next({
      status: 400, 
      message: 'User could not be updated or does not exist.'
    });
  }
};
```

Let's say our email starts off as "email@email.com" and I send a PUT request to my Edit route for the user in question with req.body.email = "newemail@email.com". The returned JSON still says "email: email@email.com". Now let's say I send another PUT request with req.body.email = "thirdemail@email.com". The returned JSON now says "email: newemail@email.com".

So the update appears to happen correctly, but the returned user object is not reflecting the update. Given the use of "await", shouldn't the user object represented by my "user" variable be the updated user record?

Answer (score 0):

OK it looks like the reason why it's bypassing the validators is already detailed here: [Why Mongoose doesn't validate on update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627967/why-mongoose-doesnt-validate-on-update)

It's still not entirely clear to me why runValidators=true doesn't activate my middleware, or why the User object returned isn't the updated version, but I'll mark this one as complete anyway.