# Mongoose unique validation triggered when saving and update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema with `unique: true` and the following validator:

```
          { // checks if email already used
                validator: async (value) => {
                    let user = await mongoose.model('User').findOne({ email: value });
                    return !user;
                },
                message: 'Email already exists'
            }
```

It works as expected when creating a new user, the problem is with updating.
I'm using `doc.save()` to update a user documents (it's a valid way to update documents according to Mongoose documentation). but that validator is being triggered again.
Is there a way to use the `save` methods without triggering that validator again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i was looking it up and actually found a Stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627967/why-mongoose-doesnt-validate-on-update).

Basically how I understand it:

While using `.save()` the validators are always triggered, but on the other hand using `.update()` doesn't (unless you specify it in the options).

Maybe try using update instead? (I know this is not a 100% answer, just trying to help)

EDIT: As discussed you can always add specific validators into your controller instead in your Schemas.

Comment: That's an option but I have other validators I want run.

Comment: What you could do is => Add the validation of your email address to your controller (express route e.g.) instead of the Schema this way you can control if you want to save the new document

Comment: That's what I ended up with.. :)

Comment: Always appreciate an upvote since I can't even like anything myself :D