# Required validation check not working for mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Schema declaration

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const reviewerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  reviewerId: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reviewer', reviewerSchema);
```

Function's code:

```
async function addReviewer(item) {
  try {
    await reviewerModal.updateOne({ email: item.email }, item, {
      upsert: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the validation check is not working and explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: so I am not getting any error even if I am not sending one of the required items and document is getting added in collection

Comment: async function addReviewer(item) {

    try {
        await reviewerModal.updateOne({
            email: item.email,
        }, item, {
            upsert: true
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

}

Comment: By using `updateOne` you are actually updating the fields passed in the `item` object of an existing `Reviewer`. The error would have been thrown in the case of the creation of a new `Reviewer` with one or some of the required properties missing. If you need to validate your `update` function you should use a library like `express-validator` https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator

Comment: so according to you in mongoose, if someone updates a field and while updating, they remove some required fields so no error will be thrown error check is done only for create ??

Comment: It is a upsert  i.e item?update:create

Comment: You can check the official docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/validation.html#:~:text=Update%20Validators&text=Mongoose%20also%20supports%20validation%20for,update()%20or%20findOneAndUpdate()%20. or this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15629463/13211263 for more info